# Power Pivot Sum across factTables

Tags: excel-2010, powerpivot, dax, measures

I'm having trouble creating a sum across multiple factTables in Power Pivot for Excel 2010.

Here's a simplified layout.

- Network A - Date, Product Name, Revenue
- Network B - Date, Product Name, Revenue
- Network C - Date, Revenue
- dimCalendar

They are all related via dimCalendar.  Network A and B have multiple products that are unique to each network.

Each network has a measure to sum its revenue, for example:
    Network A - Revenue:=SUM([Revenue])

I have created a Pivot Table that has columns for each network's revenue and rows for the date.  How can I add a column to the Pivot Table that calculates total revenue across all ad networks per day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gee, I must have had a brain cramp yesterday!  Here's my solution:

> Total Revenue:=Calculate([Network A - Revenue] + [Network B - Revenue] + [Network C - Revenue])